# Google fonts are not rendering in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, fonts, phantomjs, google-font-api

I'm using PhantomJS to capture a webpage. The page has fonts from the google fonts API. When I render the page, the font are not rendered and go back to default.

PhantomJS version: 2.0
Platform: Windows

ive added the code i use:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var args = require('system').args;

var isLoad = false;

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

page.viewportSize = { width: 1400, height: 569.1588 };

page.open('http://www.facegift.co.il/canvas/print.aspx?userItemId=27477&Sc=974088&pagenum=3&width=1500&print=2', function (status) {
setTimeout(function () {
    var ue = page.evaluate(function () {
        return window.navigator.appVersion;
    });
    console.log("status: " + status);
    console.log("ue: " + ue);

    if (status === "success") {

        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            var ps = page.evaluate(function () {
                document.body.bgColor = 'white';
                return document.getElementById("pageStatus").innerHTML;
            });


            if (!isLoad) {
                console.log("wait...");
                if (ps == "loaded") {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    console.log("proccessing...");
                    console.log("loaded");
                    isLoad = true;
                    page.render('new/exam1.png');
                    phantom.exit();
                }
            }
        }, 10);
    } else {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
}, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Have tried waiting a little until the fonts are loaded?

Comment: yes, for more then 10 seconds. but no good

Comment: Your code is quite complex. Have you tried reducing it piece-by-piece until the problem no-longer occurs? Also even though you have a 1.5 second initial delay, your later checks (if the page takes longer to load) are 100 times per second and take the image immediately after the page loads (which would give no time for the font). You would be better off waiting for the page to fully load - there are various tricks for waiting until a font has loaded. Also you should consider the case where the innerHTML is never "loaded", i.e. you should have a maximum timeout.

Comment: ok, I did that, and i found that setting the usetAgent is the problem, but when i dont set it, I return to my other issue that it doesnt rotate.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. Fonts are usually loaded after the page load is finished, so you need to wait until the fonts are loaded and the page is re-rendered, before you can take a screenshot. I don't know of an event that is potentially triggered when the fonts are loaded and applied, but my tests on your page showed that waiting 1.5 seconds is enough with PhantomJS 2.0.0:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };

page.open('http://www.facegift.co.il/canvas/print.aspx?userItemId=27477&Sc=974088&pagenum=3&width=1500&print=2', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        page.render("test40.png");
        phantom.exit();
    }, 1500);
});
```

> [image]

Comment: hey, for some reason when i used you example. it worked! .. but when i use it in my code, i doesnt. ive added my code to the question. can you please tell me what Im doing wrong there ?

Comment: it isn't fires, because it checks 'if (ps == "loaded")' the not set to loaded when page start only after every picture is loaded. in that example I dont have any picture and this is why it loads fast.

Comment: I see that now, but you haven't provide nearly enough information to diagnose your problem. The PhantomJS script is obviously not enough. This seems like a problem with your page (JavaScript/CSS/media queries). Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Comment: I've copied the exact script code, including the link to Facegift, but in my screenshot I'm seeing Times, not the "Gochi Hand" that I see on the webpage. Increasing the timeout to 15 seconds doesn't help. Using PhantomJS 2.1.1.